# Storing difficult data structure in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, datasource

I need to store this data structure in php array:
Movie has id, name and show_date. Each of show_dates have show_times. I need to dynamically in cilcle fill this array with data from my data source. When i do like this:

```
$Movie = array();
$Movie[0]['id']=10;
$Movie[0]['name']='Some Name';
$Movie[0]['date'][0]='12.12.12';
$Movie[0]['date'][0]['time'][0]='12:23:00'; //there it throws error 
$Movie[0]['date'][0]['time'][1]='15:23:00';
```

Could you help me with this issuse ?

Comment: Great. Which 'datasource'? Which 'error'? What is full structure? What did you tried?

Comment: `$Movie[0]['date'][0]` is a string (you set it as `12.12.12`) then you attempt to access it as an array: `$Movie[0]['date'][0]['time']` which it isn't.

Comment: My data source can be different - sometimes its database sometimes web site. The error is 'Could not use time as index of array' , Full data structure is Movie=>id,name,date=>date,time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do array access on a string.

Change to:

```
$Movie[0]['date'] = array();
$Movie[0]['date'][] = array( // shorthand push notation
    "date" => "12.12.12",
    "times" => array("12:23:00", "15:23:00")
);
// .. etc
```

Comment: Thank you. How it will look like inside of cicle. Like this: for(int $i=0;$i<size;$i++){ $Movie[0]['dates']['date'][0]='23.12.12'; $Movie[0]['dates']['date'][0]['times']['time'][0]='12:22';  }